# Adding CSS Trapezoid Shape :After Button

Tags: html, css, sass, css-shapes

I'm attempting to create a button style for a client, and cannot seem to get it working using the after pseudo-class.

```
<style>
$varBase: 40px;
$imsblue: #012169;
$imsgrey: #012169;

body {
  background:grey;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: $varBase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: $varBase;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: $imsblue;
  &:before {
    float: left;
    content:"";
    width: ($varBase/4);
    height: ($varBase/2);
  }
  &:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    height: ($varBase/2);
    border-left: ($varBase/2) solid $imsblue;
    border-bottom: ($varBase/2) solid transparent;
  }
  a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: ($varBase/4) ($varBase/2);
    margin-right: -10px;
  }
}
.btn3 {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(1,33,105,1) 0%, rgba(1,33,105,1) 93%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 93%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 100%);
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  a {
    color: inherit ;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: ($varBase/4) $varBase;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="btn"><a href="#">Click to Submit</a></div>
<div class="btn3"><a href="#">Click to Submit</a></div>
```

I can get it to show using two DIVs, but I need this to work with just one class. Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

It's supposed to look like this (barring color and size of course): [image: btn example]

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? What effect?

Comment: I've updated my original question with a graphic of what i thought it was going to look like. Made sense in my head.

Comment: Check your compiled CSS.  You aren't getting what you think you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the key element missing is that you need to include a `content:""` in your `:after` pseudoclass.  See the example below.

```css
.btn {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  width: 128px;
  float:left;
}

.btn:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 20px;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
    border-bottom: 20px solid white;
    float:right;
    content:"";
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Button</div>
```

Comment: OMG I feel like an idiot. Thank you so much for that. Really, that's one of those little things that wouldn't have noticed until midnight.

Answer (score 1):

This will work - I had to convert your SCSS to CSS, but it's clear enough.

```css
.btn {
  height: 40px; width: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative; /* work as container */
}
.btn:after {
  content: ''; /* needed */
  display: block;
  position: absolute; /* position to container */
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Button</div>
```

Unfortunately, you can't have "transparent" overlay, it just wont work. I had to use white for it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works where the "cut" is transparent. You can use regular background or image background for the button:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/q45w2f78/

```
<div class="buttoncut gon">My button</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gon {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  background: darkblue;
  background-size: 220px 220px;

  /* Text styling */
  line-height: 220px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  color: beige;
}
.gon:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}

.buttoncut {
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%); clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%);
  -moz-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%); clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%);
  -ms-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%); clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%); clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 60% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

I used this generator to get the correct polygon css: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Whoa! This is amazing. And I've been LOOKING for a site like that but Google was sadly not my friend.

Comment: Yes, it took me a little searching to find it. The most important word is "clip path", and after using that I found this gem. I like that clip-path: polygon actually cut away from the div rather than just covering it with a color. That means you can use the div above a background image for example.

Comment: Hmm the only problem I see is that the cut doesn't remain at a constant 45 degrees as it's based off of the length of the text inside. So if the text length is just right, you'll see 45. If it's long...it looks like a super extended cut.

Comment: I'm not giving the buttons a defined width, and if I do I risk cutting a word or two off.

Comment: As long as you have constant heigth I guess you can use 2 divs. One "end" div with a constant cut.

Comment: Here is a solution. Very quick fix, Probably some errors there... http://jsfiddle.net/q45w2f78/2/

Comment: I forgot to mention...I'll be using WordPress for this build. That's one of the main reasons I wanted to attempt a single DIV/anchor solution as it'll keep the overall code cleaner.

Comment: You can use jquery selector to add the needed divs just for the purpose of look. Not sure how to do this in a lightweight way though.

Comment: You've definitely given me a solid foundation to start off from. Thanks for your help. I'll hammer away over the next couple of days and see what I get.

Answer (score 1):

## Gradients:

You could use gradients in order to achieve this, and that way you can apply it to any element (this one's done with a button element):

```css
html,body{
  background:red;
  }

button {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 89%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 90%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1)), color-stop(89%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1)), color-stop(90%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 89%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 90%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 89%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 90%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 89%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 90%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 1) 89%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 90%, rgba(30, 87, 153, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#001e5799', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  
  outline:0;
  border:0;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<button>PressMe</button>
```

---

## Pseudo Element *(not great for gradient/image backgrounds)*

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  background:gray;
}
div:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border-bottom:10px solid blue;
  border-left:10px solid transparent;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  }
html,body{
  background:blue;
  }
```

```html
<div>Press Me!</div>
```

---

## Clip Path

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
html,body{
  background:green;
  }
```

```html
<button>press me!!!</button>
```

---

## Dynamic length

by using the following snippet, you can make a great button, which isn't affected by length!

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
button:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: -10px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid gray;
}
button:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0;
  background: gray;
}
html,
body {
  background: red;
}

/*HOVER EFFECTS*/
button:hover,
button:hover:before {
  background: yellow;
}
button:hover:after {
  border-left: 10px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<button>press me and plus i can get really long!</button>
```

Comment: I've updated my original OP code again. I had to cancel the clip path. It's only good for a fixed width button and I'm not sure how big of a button they may make. I was able to get good results with the css before and after's, and also the linear gradient. However the linear gradient poses a problem when going for super long text as well.

Comment: @bmoneruxui: that gradient could be added to a pseudo element at the end of the button. I'll edit this asap but right now i've a bit of work to do first. But it can be done by combining the two ideas. Will post tomoz deffo!

Comment: @bmoneruxui: see last snippet :)