# CSS corner cut-out on element with overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to cut out the top-left corner of a `span` element that has a top border set to it.

All works well, except for the fact that the border keeps running over the white CSS triangle. This can be fixed by removing `overflow: hidden;` from the `.contract` span's. I am, however, using the overflow to hide the text inside the span elements, so dropping that is no option.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this without altering my HTML?

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/yt887kaj/

**Screenshots:**

This is the intended look.

[image: Intended style]

This is the result with the CSS I have now, notice the top border running OVER the cut-out triangle.

[image: Current result]

Comment: why dont you remove the top border then

Comment: As you can see in the intended lay-out, the top border is required on the `.contract-active` elements.

Comment: @GerritBertier: So you need a border over the green area but not the white triangular area?

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28067256/3436942)

Comment: @GerritBertier: In that case, web-tiki's answer would be the best bet in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the after pseudo element and `z-index` to add the borders under the the white triangle.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yt887kaj/5/)**

```
.contract-start::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid #fff;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    z-index:1;
}
.contract-start::after{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #62b38f;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Comment: This removes the top border on the `.contract-active` elements.

Comment: @GerritBertier Sorry, I totaly missed the point here. I reformated the my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: Close, but you lost the border on the other `.contract-active` elements, I updated the Fiddle here to get it back. Thanks!

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yt887kaj/7/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different `box-sizing` property? I think `box-sizing: border-box` should fix your problem. http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score -1):

add border-radius for top-left corner to .contract.contract-active

```
.contract.contract-active{
border-radius: 17px 0 0 0;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/yt887kaj/4/

Comment: This results in rounded corners, which I don't want.

Comment: can you explain what do you want to do?