# Adding shadow to trapezoid

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

First of all, this question might be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450999/shadow-with-css-trapezoid-shape-button), but the shape in my case is different, so it couldn't really help me out.

The trapezoid code is the following:

```css
#light {
  /*setting the element*/
  border-bottom: 164px solid grey;
  border-left: 148px solid transparent;
  border-right: 165px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="light"></div>
```

Just to clarify, I am trying to add the shadow effect, similar to the following example:

```css
#bulb {
  /*setting the element*/
  background: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*adding "light" (shadow)*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 10px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="bulb"></div>
```

When I try to add the regular `box-shadow:`, my trapezoid becomes a regular rectangle with white parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `box-shadow` you could use a `drop-shadow` filter, e.g.

```
filter: drop-shadow(0 0 40px #222);
```

```css
#light {
 /*setting the element*/
 border-bottom: 164px solid grey;
 border-left: 148px solid transparent;
 border-right: 165px solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 80px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 40px #222);

}
```

```html
<div id="light"></div>
```

More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

I would create the shape differently using pseudo element with a blur effect:

```css
#light {
  width:400px;
  height:160px;
  position:relative;
}
#light:before,
#light:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
    /*triangle on the right*/
    linear-gradient(to top right,grey 49.5%,transparent 50%) right/150px 100%,
    /*triangle on the left*/
    linear-gradient(to top left, grey 49.5%,transparent 50%) left /150px 100%,
    /*rectangle at the center*/
    linear-gradient(grey,grey) center/100px 100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#light:before {
  filter:blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="light">

</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution and it seems almost same as the one, given by @fcalderan, the difference is that your code seems more complex than his, but as said achieving very similar goal. Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: @NewbieJ this is the purpose of giving different answers ;) same output different method.

Answer (score 0):

based on [css-tricks Double-Box Method](https://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/#article-header-id-1) you can `"have a container box with hidden overflow and another box inside it which is rotate and hangs out of it"`

```css
.light {
  width: 350px;
  height: 135px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 10px -17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.light:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #999;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="light"></div>
```

Comment: have tried your code and unless I did something wrong, the trapezoid receives the shadow around but creates some kind of black spots leaving the visible shape of a rectangle, (if I of course change the number of shadow from your "10px" to, let's say "100px". However I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

In your example, you *can't* add a proper box-shadow without having these white parts on each side. **That is because the CSS border colouring the grey shaped trapeziod DIV.**

In the example above, they are using an **.SVG file** (image), since it is an image, the original shape of it is a trapezoid, not a rectangle with white side like yours.

You will need to draw an .svg in the shape and color you want, and then add a shadow to the element itself.

[Here are more informations about SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

I hope it helps.

Comment: I partly agree with your argument but, if you look at the first example on the link, you can clearly see that the person made the shape using clean css and there was no SVG imported. Also, the answers given on this question are proving your claims a bit differently. Thanks for the reply tho :) P.S. hopefully I didn't sound harsh or anything

Comment: Hello, it is perfectly fine. I learned something from the answer above, now I know SVG isn't required to add a shadow to it. Have a good day :)

Comment: likewise @Alexis Philip